# error 1064 while creating mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, mariadb, procedure

I am creating mySql procedure in HeidiSql:

```
   CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE checkSchedule
 ( IN sDate date, IN eDate date, IN sTime time, IN eTime time, IN weekDay int(7), IN classId int(11) )
   BEGIN 
   select schedule.idSchedule 
       from schedule 
          where ( (sDate>=schedule.startDate and sDate<=schedule.endDate) 
       or (sDate<=schedule.startDate and eDate>=schedule.endDate) 
       or (eDate>=schedule.startDate and eDate<=schedule.endDate) ) 
       and ( (sTime>=schedule.startTime and sTime<=schedule.endTime) 
       or (sTime<=schedule.startTime and eTime>=schedule.endTime) 
       or (eTime>=schedule.startTime and eTime<=schedule.endTime) ) 
       and weekDay=schedule.weekDay and classId=schedule.classroom_idClassRoom; 
    END
```

and I am getting the next error:

```
    SQL Error (1064): check the manual corresponds your MariaDB server 
    version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 12
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not that difficult andsDate should be and sdate AND if you have set delimiters then things should be fine https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: @P.Salmon actually, in my code andsDate is and sDate, it was problem of pasting code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change DELIMITER temporary to execute the procedure.
Default DELIMITER is `;` but while creating the procedure you use  `;` so it creates problems.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE checkSchedule
 ( IN sDate date, IN eDate date, IN sTime time, IN eTime time, IN weekDay int(7), IN classId int(11) )
   BEGIN 
   select schedule.idSchedule 
       from schedule 
          where ( (sDate>=schedule.startDate and sDate<=schedule.endDate) 
       or (sDate<=schedule.startDate and eDate>=schedule.endDate) 
       or (eDate>=schedule.startDate and eDate<=schedule.endDate) ) 
       and ( (sTime>=schedule.startTime and sTime<=schedule.endTime) 
       or (sTime<=schedule.startTime and eTime>=schedule.endTime) 
       or (eTime>=schedule.startTime and eTime<=schedule.endTime) ) 
       and weekDay=schedule.weekDay and classId=schedule.classroom_idClassRoom; 
    END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/svGMffct6rEStwtX5ho1DL/12)